# Showing that $f :\mathbb{N}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ $p(a,b) = \frac{(a+1)b(b+1)}{2}$ is not an injection

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I said that this function is not an injection because $p(1, 2) = 6 = p(5, 1)$

But it is not always easy to find values and I wanted to know if there was a way of showing its not an injection by deriving a contraction using the definition of injection.

given $p(a, b) = p(c,d)$

$\frac{(a+1)b(b+1)}{2}$ = $\frac{(c+1)d(d+1)}{2}$

I get really confused when dealing with function with $R^2$ and now since there are 4 different variables I don't really know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your example isn't quite right. $p(1,2) = \frac{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3}{2} = 9$.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I corrected it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a general rule.  In this case I first noticed that $a$ and $c$ each only appear once, so I could try to pick useful values for $b,d$ and choose $a,c$ to fit.  The trick seems to be getting the factors $b,b+1$ accounted for, so maybe we choose $b=3, d=8$.  That way $b(b+1)=12, d(d+1)=72,$ so $b(b+1)$ divides into $d(d+1)$.  Now we need $(a+1)=6(c+1), a=6c+5$.  We find $p(11,3)=p(1,8)=72$

Another way is to recognize that you can let $a$ be whatever it needs to be as long as $b$ is small so its divisors are covered.  Let $b=1$ and you can write $(a+1)1(1+1)=(c+d)d(d+1), a=\frac 12(c+1)d(d+1)-1$.  Pick $c,d$ as you wish and compute $a$.

Comment: For the part at the bottom basically If I show that a!=c  that that would be enough right? $a = 1/2(c+2)(2(2+1)) = 1/2(6c +12) = 3c + 6$ , by picking c as 2, a=12, thus a!=c

Comment: I updated my answer in light of your update to the question, but generally yes if you show you can get the same value for $p(a,b)$ and $p(c,d)$ with $a \neq c$ you are done.